# How to scale an element when it loads using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, transform, scale

I'm loading an element that has the initial css values of :

```
.popOver {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #d9dfe5;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out; 
  transform: scale(0,0); 
}
```

I need to change to scale(1, 1) when the element loads in the page and see the transition. Anyone can help?

Comment: When the element loads it will get the css you've written, if you want the element to get `scale(1,1)` after(i.e on document loads), javascript(or jquery) should be used.

Comment: @Xlander jQuery isn't required for this

Comment: @Mr.Alien, the OP wanted an animation?

Comment: @Xlander Yes - *when the element loads in the page and see the transition* as far as I understand

Comment: @Mr.Alien, Ah ok, nevermind then.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`transition` will apply the moment you load the page so that is not an ideal solution in your situation, what you will need is CSS `@keyframes` where you need to set `scale(0,0)` to the `class` and then `scale(1,1)` for `100%` as *keyframes* will shoot after the page is completely loaded.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3w80ja6m/2/) *(Refactored the code a bit and added `animation-fill-mode` to prevent the popup from scaling back to `0` so using rev 2)*

```
.popOver {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #d9dfe5;
    -webkit-animation: bummer 2s;
    animation: bummer 2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0,0); 
    transform: scale(0,0);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Add this so that your modal doesn't 
                                      close after the animation completes */
}

@-webkit-keyframes bummer {
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1,1); 
    }
}

@keyframes bummer {
    100% {
        transform: scale(1,1); 
    }
}
```

Here as I explained before, am setting the initial scale of the element to `0,0` and than am animating it to `1,1` using keyframes. The time of the animation can be controlled by tweaking the `2s` which is nothing but *2 Seconds*.